# How to update the tableview after adding the object

Tags: ios

How to update the tableview after adding the  object .

I am doing in the mvvm ,

So

in cartviewmodel:-

```
var datasourceModel: DataSourceModel


var insertedArray: Model? 

var finalArray: Array<Model>? = []


func add()  {

            datasourceModel.dataListArray?.append(insertedArray!)
            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)

            self.datasourceModel.dataListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray

    }
```

In tableview cell i have used a button for adding.

So in viewcontroller i have done the action on the add button 
AND thus it will add and display the other viewcontroller.

my hotelviewcontroller as:-

the code for add button action...

```
cell.cartaddCell = {[weak self] in
             if let i = self?.tableView.indexPath(for: $0) {


            let cartDataSource:DataSourceModel = DataSourceModel(array: nil)
            let cartViewModel:ViewModel = ViewModel(withdatasource: cartDataSource)


            let cartmodel:Model = Model(withoffermodel:self!.offerViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))


            cartViewModel.insertedArray = cartmodel
            print(cartViewModel.insertedArray)
            cartViewModel.add()


            let cartViewController:ViewController  = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil, withViewModel: cartViewModel)


            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(cartViewController, animated: true)
            // self?.present(cartViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            // print(cartViewModel.insertedArray )

            print(cartmodel.offerprice)
            print(cartmodel.offerdetailAddName)
            print(cartmodel)
            print(i)
           // self?.chartViewModel.delete(atIndex: i)
       }
    }
```

now in my cartviewmodel as:-

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {


    var datasourceModel:DataSourceModel


    var insertedArray:Model? 

    var finalArray:Array<Model>? = []


    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: DataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)

    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> Model{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return datasourceModel.dataListArray!.count
    }

    func delete(atIndex indexPath: IndexPath) {

        datasourceModel.dataListArray!.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    }

    func add()  {

            datasourceModel.dataListArray?.append(insertedArray!)
            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray)

      self.datasourceModel.dataListArray = datasourceModel.dataListArray


    }




    func insert(){
      add()
    datasourceModel.dataListArray!.insert(insertedArray?.offerdetailAddName, at: indexPath.row)

    }
}
```

my cartviewcontroller:-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITabBarDelegate{

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderbutton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var displayresult: UIView!



    private var chartViewModel :ViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:ViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        chartViewModel = viewModel
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.86, blue: 1, alpha:1.0)


        tableView.dataSource = self

        displayresult.isHidden = false



        self.tableView .reloadData()
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = displayresult


    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return chartViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "cell"
        var cell: ChartCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ChartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell
        }

        cell.setEventData(charts: chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))




     print(chartViewModel.insertedArray)


               return cell
    }





   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if editingStyle == .delete {

            chartViewModel.delete(atIndex: indexPath)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Actually i have 2 screens.
1.hotelscreen
2.cartscreen

So while clicking the hoteltableviewcell a have a button to add cart .

So while adding the hotel model will added in the cart screen.

for that i got the value already.

But my question is:-

when i clicked on the cartscreen the added object is not displayed.

So how to show the updated data.

Comment: did you try with `hotelTableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need is `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: i have given ,but the added object is not displaying while clicking on cart screen

Comment: i have added my cart view controller,please check ..what is the solution